# Filtering Rows in R on Mutliple Conditional Test

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, rows

So am trying to filter rows of a data.frame based on the condition of having two or more 0 values.

```
    mir Target_2 Score value_2  Blank
1   BERKSHIRE   BERKS   77  0   0
2   FRANKLIN    FRANK   81  5   0
3   HAMPDEN     DEN     69  4   0
4   HAMPSHIRE   HAMP    75  0   0
5   MIDDLESEX   SEX     47  0   0
6   WORCHESTER  SEX     0   2   0
7   WORCHESTER  WOR     64  0   0
8   BERKSHIR    BERKS   0   3   0
9   HAMPHIRE    HAMP    0   4   0
```

An example data frame is above and I need help returning the values that have only one zero value in the row. For the purposes of this example I included a column with all zeros, but my data will not be so clean. So I wonder if there is a conditional like below:

```
 If col[value] == 0:
         if col+1[value] == 0:
            filter
         elif col+2[value] == 0:
            filter
         elif col+n[value] == 0:
           filter
```

I would like the output of the function applied to the test table:

```
   mir Target_2 Score value_2   Blank
    2   FRANKLIN    FRANK   81  5   0
    3   HAMPDEN     DEN     69  4   0
```

Comment: Question is a duplicate, but I believe the way I asked my question is more succinct and searchable. Cheers, Cody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
> df[apply(df[3:5], 1, function(x) table(x)['0']==1), ]
       mir Target_2 Score value_2 Blank
2 FRANKLIN    FRANK    81       5     0
3  HAMPDEN      DEN    69       4     0
```

It uses function `table` to count frequencies for each of the numbers. If the frequency of `0` is 1 then it returns `TRUE` for that line. Then this is used to subset the `df` accordingly.

Comment: Perfect!! Cheers, Cody